# Execute script from server to server php

Tags: php, curl, php-5.3, postman

I need to call one URL without the browser. I have tried with POSTMAN. its working fine. Not sure how to do it via Server to server in PHP ?

Is there any online service available for these kind of trigger. Tried cron job too but not working as expected. Any help??

Comment: CRON is only for task schedule. Solution is cURL, you even tagged that question. 1. write script with cURL 2. set up CRON?

Comment: just need to call it? `<?php get_headers("http://url");?>` - done.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://codular.com/curl-with-php). Hope it will help. 
 This is just the basic curl request.